# How does typescript abbreviate a type in vue as a global type

Tags: typescript2.7

Now it is like this:

```js
<template>
    <Form ref="formRef" />
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>
import { UnwrapRef } from 'vue';
import { RefValue } from 'vue/macros';
import Form from './Form.vue';

let formRef: RefValue<UnwrapRef<InstanceType<typeof Form>>> = $ref();
</script>
```

I want:

```js
<template>
    <Form ref="formRef" />
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>
import Form from './Form.vue';

let formRef: UnRef<Form> = $ref();
```

How to define a global type in env.d.ts without having to import it every time it is used

```js
import { UnwrapRef } from 'vue';
import { RefValue } from 'vue/macros';

type UnRef<T> = RefValue<UnwrapRef<InstanceType<typeof T>>>
```

Because import is used here, it is not global. How can we define the whole world?

Answer (score 0):

Use: declare global

```js
import { UnwrapRef } from 'vue';
import { RefValue } from 'vue/macros';
declare global {
    type UnRef<T> = RefValue<UnwrapRef<InstanceType<typeof T>>>
}
```